# Does Android support Geo Fencing on Google maps and what is earliest platform that support Geo fencing?

Tags: android, google-maps, platform, geofencing

is there support for geo fencing on Android if yes then what is the earliest platform that support Geo fencing feature.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497977/how-to-notify-user-when-he-entered-into-a-movie-theater-in-android might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Google Maps, do you mean the Android location manager? The Google Maps application itself doesn't appear to have that feature built in.

Depending on what you're planning to use it for, you could most definitely implement a simple geofencing feature yourself using the GPS libraries (i.e. `LocationManager`) and a simple collision detection algorithm like point-in-polygon or a bounding box check, and display it on a map control.

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't support at the time of your question but Google just released that feature as part of Google IO 2013:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.html