# How to notify user when he entered into a Movie theater in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, geofencing

In my android app i ve map view and current location,nearest theaters  displayed now i want to notify user when he entered into a theater(like geofence) i searched on NET and dint find any Android api which supports Geofencing please help how to do it?

Note:I tried http://geofence.locationlabs.com/  but not working means API keys are not comig.
any example code really helpful Thanks in advance

Comment: Does a user really need to be notified when they've entered a theater? Chances are they already know.

Comment: Here we can take this like a user in a particular region then we send some alert on his device.

Comment: @KrishnakantDalal yes some thing like that..how can i do that

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes when user entered theater he has to notified ..and i want to send this notification to facebook...

Comment: I am still searching and waiting for positive reply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey I found the solution Try This,

We have to implement PendingIntent & Location Manager. Location Manager obtain the current Location of user and when user entered in some region it will fire a pending intent some code snippet as follow:

```
//---use the LocationManager class to obtain locations data---
lm = (LocationManager)
getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
//---PendingIntent to launch activity if the user is within some locations---
PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
this, 0, new
Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.com")), 0);
lm.addProximityAlert(37.422006, -122.084095, 5, -1, pendIntent);
```

addProximityAlert method in which we can set the region (Radius for the User tracking)
[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) is the more detail of addProximityAlert method.

Comment: @PSrinivasgoud: I am also trying the same concept. I am a blackberry developer. I am literally new to android. Can you explain me little more about this or can you provide me any code sample on this ??

Comment: @ArunKumarMunusamy refer this link:http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html